# Django "static" files - Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

Minor terminology question: I see Django refers to images, CSS and Javascript scripts as "static" files (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). However, a Javascript script is not static, it is dynamic; it executes in the client when the web page is loaded. I suppose the "static" terminology used by Django is in the server perspective, where Javascript scripts and images are equally static and provided as they are to the client ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - static files mean that their content is static, not that they are not in some way evaluated (images and CSS files are also evaluated - I think you're using the term "static" in a fairly unusual way).

Comment: Probably because I come from a non-server/client development background where I am used to split a project simply in code, non-code resources and documentation. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

static is relative to 'server side' language .such as php,jsp,they can communicate with database like mysql,further ,they may present different content to browser.  But static will never change its content to browser without any modification.